# Dynamically setting the id jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts-1

There's a table and it's rows are being populated by iterating using nested:iterate in struts.

I want to set an id of one of the  tags using the values of

```
    nested:write property="somePropertyName"
```

So i can dynamically hide and show it depending on a click action. 
For an example

```
  <a onclick="hideShowTable()" style="cursor:hand" id="Data retrieved - to uniquely identification"> &#43; &nbsp; </a>
```

How to do this?

Comment: How do you do what? It seems you know how to pass the ID value to the included JSP and you know how to create a link with an `onclick` event handler. What is your question?

Comment: that id attribute should have the nested:write property="somePropertyName"  value

Comment: Please show us all relevant code that you already have (trim things that we don't need, please), error messages, output that you get and output which you would like to see.

Comment: Which taglib are you using with the `nested:...` prefix? That is, can you show us the `<%@ taglib prefix="nested" uri="____" %>` from the top of your .jsp?